# How can I make this function that checks whether a number is a palindrome better?

Tags: algorithm, typescript

I have this code:

```js
export function is_palindrome(num: number): boolean {
    return [...num.toString()].reverse().join("") === num.toString();
}
```

which checks if a number is a palindrome(i.e 9009 reversed is still 9009), I do this by using the spread operator on `num.toString()`, reversing the array, joining it, and then comparing it to `num.toString()` which works but surely there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine - note that for a function this small there will almost always be no real impact on runtime, nor on readability. The only thing I would change is avoiding converting `num` into a string twice.

It is also possible to check for a palindrome without explicitly reversing the string, which I have done below.

```js
export function is_palindrome(num: number): boolean {
    const str = num.toString();
    const len = str.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(len / 2); i++) {
        if (str[i] !== str[len - i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Unless denoting the type of the variable is required for TS to compile, or if it's not immediately clear upon reading the code, some might prefer to leave out the explicit type annotations. Especially in longer functions, it can start to look extraneous and can detract from the reading of the code's main logic.